# On Craft Client, what does the client account get?

Tags: control-panel, admin

A definitive description of the client account would be useful for this. What does a client account get? For example, can they clear the cache?

I know I can login and find this out myself, but it would be helpful to have a go-to article on this for future reference.

Comment: As far as i'm aware the only limitations are what is displayed on the pricing page http://buildwithcraft.com/pricing . If its not compared against here I would assume it's possible across all packages, but feel free to correct me if im wrong :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/users#clients-account):

> The Client’s Account is not an Admin account like yours, so they will not be able to access the Settings section or administrate your Admin account. They’ll be able to do everything else, though.

Comment: Thanks. Any plans to add the ability for this kind of account to clear the caches?

Comment: Not really. Maybe possible with something like [this plugin](https://github.com/themccallister/craft.cache-clear/), though.